# Virtual Machine Vs. Middleware

Tags: operating-system, virtualization, virtual-machine, middleware

What are the differences between a Virtual Machine and a Middleware? Can I consider a Virtual Machine as a Middleware? Can I use a middleware for the Virtual Machines?

Comment: This is a programming site.  This question belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`Middleware` is a broad term which is used to refer to components or modules in a system, which sit beneath the applications (usually the top most layer) but on top of lower layers (like hardware abstraction, drivers, kernel, etc.).

`Virtual Machine` is just an actual physical machine implemented in software. One class of VMs run only a single process like (JVM, all interpreted languages, etc.), and there are other classes which could emulate an entire system and hence run an operating system on top of the VM.

As you can see, these 2 terms cannot be compared directly without any context, which unfortunately is not clear from your question.

Comment: Your description for Middleware is not right. Middleware sit between two programs not between application and hardware. For example anything which sit between OS and applications is a middleware. Virtual Machine is an program which simulates(or emulates) a hardware+OS behaviour for another application. Therefore Virtual Machine is sits between hardware and application.